# Cordova JQueryMobile Menu not floating on ios device

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

My header and footer menus are looking great on ios emulator all versions, but not floating on the two real devices ipad 2 or iPhone 5. What's wrong? I'm using jQuerymobile 1.4.5 and jQuery 1.9.1 with latest cordova build and platforms all updated.
I've cleaned, removed the platform, re-added it. Also looks good in browser. Any clues?

[image: Not floating on ipad]

[image: Playing nicely on the emulator]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.thegatewaychurch.info/; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; media-src * https://www.thegatewaychurch.info/; img-src 'self' https://www.thegatewaychurch.info/ data:">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width height=100%" />
    <title>The Gateway Church</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" >
    <div data-role="page" id="page">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d">
                <ul id="header-menu">
                    <li id="home-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Home</li>
                    <li id="address-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#address"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Address</li>
                    <li id="media-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#media"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-media" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Media</li>
                    <li id="rota-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#rota"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-rota" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Rotas</li>
                    <li id="giving-tab-button" class="tab-button"  data-tab="#giving"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-coins" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Giving </li>
                </ul>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main" class="ui-content" >

            <div id="rendered" >
                <div id="content"><p class="center"><img src="img/thegateway-logo.png" class="responsive"/></p><h3>Join the adventure...</h3><p>The Gateway Church is a multi-cultural charismatic Church in King's Lynn, Norfolk. You'll be sure of a very warm welcome any Sunday 10am at King's Lynn Academy on Queen Mary Road.</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
            <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d">
                <ul id="footer-menu">

                    <li id="calendar-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#calendar"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Calendar</li>
                                            <li id="news-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#news"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-newspaper" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>News</li>
                    <li id="group-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#smallgroup"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-group" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Groups</li>
                    <li id="prayer-tab-button" class="tab-button" data-tab="#prayer"  data-tap-toggle="false"><span id="pray"  aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Prayer</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->

        </div>
    </div>    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryMobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jQueryMD5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it's not picking up the style sheet. The real devices often have issues with relative addressing that the emulator doesn't.

Comment: Although it is picking up the glyphicons in that style sheet and the Prayer icon is an svg referenced in the stylesheet. What would absolute addressing look like on an ios build?